# Number of roots over the rationals of a multivariate polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

Let $P(x_1,\dots,x_m)$ be a polynomial with $N$ roots over the rationals. If $N$ is finite, is there a known upper bound on $N$ in terms of $m$ and the degree $d$ of the polynomial? For $m=1$, an obvious bound is $d$.

P.S.: i am realizing that it is very hard to find such a bound. So, let me restate the problem. It is always possible to find a polynomial with a number $N$ of rational roots at least equal to the number of coefficients minus-1, say $N_0$. For large degree, $N_0$ scales as $d^m/m!$. To find such a polynomial, it is sufficient to generate $N_0$ random rational points and compute the coefficients so that the points are zeros of the polynomial. So, my question is as follows. Is the total number of zeros typically equal to about $N_0$ under this construction in the asymptotic limit of high degree? Or better, is it hard to find polynomials with $N$ much greater than $N_0$?  I am still assuming that the total number is finite.

P.S2.: in the meantime, I found a better construction that  gives at least $d^m$  rational roots, that is, about $m!$ times the previous value $N_0$.
The polynomial is defined as
$$
\sum_{s=1}^m\prod_{i=1}^d a_{i,s},
$$
where $a_{i,s}$ are linear polynomials with rational coefficients.

At this point, I will accept an answer that provides an even better construction.

Comment: I don't think so. It is very hard to make statements about rational points of general hypersurfaces, unless they can be embedded in an abelian variety. I think the right analogue of the case $m=1$ is the number of irreducible components of the variety defined by $P$. In that case, there is such an upper bound because the polynomials of degree $\leq d$ form a bounded family and because geometric irreducibility of the fibre of a family is a constructible property.

Comment: A sharp upper bound is just $d$, I believe... (because the irreducible components correspond to the the irreducible factors of $P$). The argument I gave above holds in a more general situation.

Comment: Your question would be totally open if the $n = 2$, i.e., the polynomial defines an affine plane curve. For larger number of variables this question is basically hopeless.

Comment: Well, one could provide a construction such that the number of roots is greater than $N_0$. For example, I found in the meantime a construction such that $N$ is at least equal to $d^m$, which is about $m!$ times greater than $N_0$.